# unable to upload file with special character in Spring java

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

while uploading a file with special character name of `file e- F CINE HD 1Break Sin Créd.mxf` and it gets file name changed `E- F CINE HD 1Break Sin Cre?D.Mxf` of the special character in UI but name remain same in my database which have been uploaded.

and I got this error:

```
Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x64  at [Source: io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl@4e6aff3c; line: 1, column: 735]
```

Comment: The file name is incorrectly encoded.  You most likely have ISO-Latin-1 instead of UTF-8

Comment: i tried that way but still i am getting same error.<setHeader headerName="Exchange.HTTP_METHOD">
                <constant>POST</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <setHeader headerName="Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE">
                <constant>application/json</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <setHeader headerName="Exchange.CHARSET_NAME">
                <constant>utf-8</constant>
            </setHeader>

Answer (score 0):

Try this config: Add this config in your `web.xml` file.
Make sure you are adding the correct encoding value.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>ISO-Latin-1</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: <constant>POST</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <setHeader headerName="Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE">
                <constant>application/json</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <setHeader headerName="Exchange.CHARSET_NAME">
                <constant>UTF-8</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <setHeader headerName="MediaCentreUsername">
                <constant>admin</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <to uri="{{camel.route.fuse.api.url.aspera}}"/>
            <to uri="{{camel.route.fuse.log.topic}}"/>

Comment: Where are you adding this? Have you tried using above config in web.xml?